# Passing two variables to function, then appending HTML content

Tags: javascript

I have the following JavaScript code:

```
 <script>
    var test1 = 44.22644865;
    var test2 = 17.66116217;

   $("#inner_poslovnica_info").append("<div class='sakrij_temp' id='detalji' onclick='PokreniMapu("test1,test2");'></div></div>");

 </script>

 <script>

  function PokreniMapu(sirina, visina){
        $("#google_mapa").show();
sirinaGeo = sirina;
visinaGeo = visina;
var myOptions = {zoom:16,center:new google.maps.LatLng(sirinaGeo, visinaGeo),mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP};
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("google_mapa"), myOptions);

marker = new google.maps.Marker({
map: map,position: new google.maps.LatLng(sirinaGeo, visinaGeo)});

//infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
//content:"<b>The Circle</b><br/>2880 Broadway<br/> New York" });

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(){infowindow.open(map,marker);});
infowindow.open(map,marker);

}

 </script>
```

This does not work. I can not pass variable using `onclick='PokreniMapu("test1,test2");'`.

Also, `onclick='PokreniMapu("+test1,""+test2+");' does not work.

Values are not "pushed" to the called function; thus, the map does not show up.

I'm using the `append` function to put HTML content in a `<div>` tag. What could be the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: `onclick='PokreniMapu("test1","test2");'` should do the trick. Since each argument is a string, they must be individually wrapped in quotes, but also separated by a comma to actually deliver them as individual arguments to your `PokreniMapu(arg1, arg2)` function.

Comment: I don't think you need the double-quotes; I think `onclick='PokreniMapu(test1, test1)';` should work. I can't confirm that though, so I'm not going to answer.

Comment: Did any of the answers meet your needs? If so, could you mark the answer of your choice as accepted, or else leave a comment?

Answer (score 0):

This line has an error:

```
$("#inner_poslovnica_info").append("<div class='sakrij_temp' id='detalji' onclick='PokreniMapu("test1,test2");'></div></div>");
```

When the interpreter reaches PokreniMapu(" it thinks the `"` means you intend to close the string, and then it gives an error because it doesn't understand the rest.

Try it this way:

```
$("#inner_poslovnica_info").append("<div class='sakrij_temp' id='detalji' onclick='PokreniMapu("+test1+","+test2+");'></div></div>");
```

This should work, since test1 and test2 are numeric values. If they were strings you should escape a simple colon:

```
$("#inner_poslovnica_info").append("<div class='sakrij_temp' id='detalji' onclick='PokreniMapu(\'"+test1+"\',\'"+test2+"\');'></div></div>");
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in comments the following line is not valid JavaScript:

```
$("#inner_poslovnica_info").append(
  "<div class='sakrij_temp' id='detalji' onclick='PokreniMapu("test1,test2");'></div></div>");
```

The second double quote is followed by a variable name, which is invalid. You'll also want to remove the duplicate closing `</div>`.

You could use concatenation there, and inject a `+` to get this:

```
"<div ... onclick='PokreniMapu(" + test1 + "," + test2 + ");'></div>"
```

Or, if the `test1` and `test2` variables still have the correct values at the time of the `click` event, you can embed the variables, just like the function call, in the string:

```
"<div ... onclick='PokreniMapu(test1,test2);'></div>"
```

#### Better alternative

But I would advise against adding code as a string. In my opinion it is better to handle the `click` event as follows:

```
$("<div class='sakrij_temp' id='detalji'>")
    .appendTo('#inner_poslovnica_info')
    .click(function() {
        PokreniMapu(test1, test2);
    });
```

Or, making use of `bind()`:

```
$("<div class='sakrij_temp' id='detalji'>")
    .appendTo('#inner_poslovnica_info')
    .click(PokreniMapu.bind(this, test1, test2));
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks to all, I have tried this and it works.

```
onclick='PokreniMapu("+test1+","+test2+");'
```

I will try this also. I have never used bind()  before, I'll give it a try.